# Is there a standard pattern for cross-site JSON requests?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I am a new web developer but I'm encountering what I assume would be a fairly common scenario.

I have a web site at www.mysite.com (testing from localhost) and the client is requesting a JSON object from a REST service I host at data.mysite.com (live service, not using a test version).  I am making this request using JQuery's $.ajax() function.  When I attempt this, I get a notice (in chrome) that I need the response header to contain  Access-Control-Allow-Origin configuration for this domain (localhost).

I did some digging and understand that there are several ways to resolve this.  I'm wondering which one makes the most sense for me.

**Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header information to the HTTP Response.**

I dislike this as it is not browser agnostic, and also could be a point of maintenance agony as standards evolve.

**Make a JSONP request**

This seems like a standard answer, but it doesn't seem like it aligns with the REST service pattern very well and coming from a systems engineering/desktop application development platform, feels like a dirty hack.

**Route all off-site requests through the local domain**

Letting the server make the request on my behalf has two major issues.  One is that it turns one asynchronous latency inducing call into two.  The other is that if the API changes for the REST service, I may have to evolve the local implementation accordingly which means twice as much maintenance.

**Other options?**

I'm sincerely hoping that StackOverflow has other ideas or suggestions for handling this sort of scenario, as the idea of cross site requests of this form seem like they would be a common occurrence, however I understand the security implications of opening up the client to this sort of cross-site call dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually opted for joining the two domains (since I owned both) and hosting both locally.  With that being said, CORS, seemed to be the best way to go, but it is still new so your mileage may vary.  Also, creating a proxy as per my 3rd suggestion was quite viable, but of course had caveats.